# What is best solution for update version of css file

Tags: asp.net, css

I usually after css modification, change the version of css file in master.
then i must upload css file and master file.
is there any solution to change css version without need to upload master.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/themes/default/style.css?v2") %>" type="text/css"/>
```

i am using asp.net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing how you do not want to change anything but the CSS file itself you could write a custom method which wraps `ResolveURL` and appends the last modified date of the css file in a set format (i.e. `MMddyyhhmmss`). This would automatically update whenever the file gets changed.

Something along the lines of:

```
    <link href="<%= VersionCssUrl("~/Styles/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

C#:

```
    public string VersionCssUrl(string url)
    {
        // Get physical path.
        var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(url);

        return String.Format("{0}?{1}", 
            ResolveUrl(url), 
            File.GetLastWriteTime(path).ToString("MMddyyhhmmss"));
    }
```

Alternatively, it might be worth looking into any of these:

- [Shinkansen](http://shinkansen.codeplex.com/)
- [ClientDependency](http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/)
- [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/), as mentioned by TJB
- [.NET built-in bundling](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: I like this idea. Maybe Just do it when you are in deboug build.

Answer (score 1):

**There are lots of automated solutions for this now-a-days**

Cassette @ http://getcassette.net/ is open source

- It will detect changes in the .css files and if you use [their markup](http://getcassette.net/documentation/getting-started/webforms) it will [automatically append a hash](http://getcassette.net/documentation/getting-started) (so you don't even have to manually update the version!)

They have installation via Nuget which simplifies the configuration / setup.